# How long was the Back to the Future trilogy from Marty's point of view?

Tags: back-to-the-future

The title pretty much says it all. From the start of *Back to the Future*, how much time passed for Marty by the end of *Back to the Future III*?

Comment: I'm just making a wild guess here, but the first movie seemed to take place over the course more than a week.  probably a month or so, the second movie would have been a lot shorter.  Probably a day's worth there.  I don't remember the third movie as well, but I feel like it would have only taken a few days.  I could be way off

Comment: I don't remember If they tell you any specific dates, but There are a number of notable events that you should see if you can get the date of( that is if you can't just scrape the dates off the delorian dashboard).  Try to look for the dates of the dance, the lightning storm(i think they're the same date), the death of whoever would have been ran off the tracks, the date of doc's supposed death.  the date at the end of the second movie when marty gets his letter, and there are probably a few other places where you can glean dates from.  It shouldn't be too difficult

Comment: First movie I *think* was about a week... IIRC, Marty makes a statement about how he can hang out in 1955 for a week (at which Doc gets indignant). For 2, I think @SamIam is right, ... a couple days, maybe a week. 3 was a week or less... because Marty went back, found Doc, and then told him the date he'd get shot, and Doc made some comment about 'That's next Monday!' (or whatever day it was). So that was about a week. So I figure the whole thing was 2, 2 1/2 weeks, 3 weeks, tops.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I would say ~19 days as listed out below:

**BTTF 1** Total ~8.5 days

Marty goes to the Doc's house in the morning. He blows out the windows. Marty meets his friend, scientist Dr. Emmett "Doc" Brown, late that night in the parking lot of a deserted shopping mall,

~1 Day

Doc enters the date November 5, 1955, the date he came up with the concept of the flux capacitor. Marty goes back in time to 1955.  Marty shows Doc a flyer he received in 1985, which states that lightning will strike the courthouse clock tower the following Saturday November 12 at 10:04 pm. That night Marty goes back to 1985 after ~1 week in 1955.

~ 7 days

He gets up the next morning and leaves for the future.

~ .5 days

**BTTF 2**  Total ~3 days

On 26 October 1985, Dr. Emmett Brown arrives in his DeLorean time machine and persuades Marty McFly and his girlfriend, Jennifer Parker, to come with him to the future. They arrive on 21 October 2015,Biff uses the DeLorean to travel to 1955, where he gives his teenage self the almanac, before returning to 2015. Marty, Doc, and an unconscious Jennifer return to 1985 (that night), unaware of Biff's actions.

~ 1 day

Marty and Doc arrive at night. They find a completely different Hill Valley. They try to figure out what happened.  Marty confronts Biff.  ....  Doc arrives and incapacitates Biff, allowing him and Marty to flee to 1955.

~ 1 day

Marty secretly follows the 1955 Biff and witnesses him receive the almanac from his older self (November 12). That night is the concert. After a struggle, Marty takes the almanac from Biff, who crashes his car into a manure truck as Doc and Marty fly away in the DeLorean. With Doc hovering above in the DeLorean as a storm approaches, Marty burns the almanac on the ground and undoes Biff's damage to history. However, the time machine is struck by lightning and disappears. A courier from Western Union arrives minutes later and hands Marty a 70-year-old letter from Doc, who was sent back in time to 1885 by the lightning strike and is now trapped. Marty races back into town and finds the 1955 Doc who, seconds earlier, helped the original Marty from the first time-travel incident return to 1985. Doc is shocked by his friend's sudden reappearance and faints.

~ 1 day

**BTTF 3** Total ~7.5 days

On November 12, 1955, Marty McFly discovers that his friend, Dr. Emmett "Doc" Brown, has become trapped in 1885. Marty, with the 1955 Doc, uses the information in Doc's 1885 letter to locate and repair the DeLorean. He spots a tombstone with Doc's name, dated **six days after the letter.** Learning that Doc was killed by Biff Tannen's great-grandfather, Buford "Mad Dog" Tannen, Marty travels back to 1885 to save Doc.

~ 1 day

He arrives on September 2, 1885, Marty meets Biff "Mad Dog" Tanner and Doc. Doc saves Clara, etc. and goes to party Buford goads Marty into a showdown **in two days' time.** In the photograph of Doc's tombstone, Doc's name has disappeared, but the date on the tombstone remains unchanged. Doc warns Marty that he, not Doc, might be killed by Buford. **The night before their departure,** Marty and Doc place the DeLorean onto the rail spur. Events occur.....
They coast away from the train as the DeLorean disappears through time, while the locomotive falls off the unfinished bridge.

~ 6 days.

Marty arrives on October 27, 1985.  He and Jennifer go driving. Forgoes racing. Doesn't crash, meets Doc.

~ .5 days.

Total 19 days give or take.

Comment: Makes me feel a little unimpressive when I think about how little I usually get done in 19 days.

Comment: Excellent answer - I really appreciate how you not only gave the answer, but also provided your methodology!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Yeah, but I'm sure you can get a lot accomplished in 19 days spread over 130 years. :P

Comment: @krillgar: I’d try to spend most of it in 1885, they didn’t have Bejewelled and Threes back then.

Comment: I disagree with your assessment of the second movie.  Doc and Marty arrive in Dark Hill Valley at night, and they likewise depart when it's dark outside.  True that Marty got knocked out at one point there, but we never actually see daytime in the alternate Hill Valley.  Given that they return to Nov. 12 1955 and see the sun rise, I get the feeling that they went through a night in Hill Valley without ever hitting daybreak.  That puts the day count at ~2, not ~3.

Comment: @beichst I'd suggest adding another 1-3 days. At the beginning of BTTF Part 3, it is late 11/12/55, and by the end of the credits, the next morning, 11/13. After reading the letter, cut to blasting the mine entrance, which seems like dusk, then load the Delorean and find Doc's tombstone, it's night. Assuming they repair the Delorean overnight, the drive-in scene where Marty departs for 1885 is the next day, 11/14. This is an ambitious schedule, for Doc to get the explosives, tow truck, car trailer, time circuit parts, new tires, mining equipment, etc. in less than a day. I'd add 3 days.